# JPanel resize flickering

Tags: java, swing, resize, graphics2d, flicker

I draw a (co)sinusoid signal in the time domain using a JPanel and overriding its paintComponent(Graphics g).
When i do a resize my application starts flickering and appears a black background until the resizing is not finished.
Is there a way to prevent this sort of flickering?
Thanks in advance.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class AnotherSignalGraph extends JPanel {

    private double offset = 0.0;
    private double scaleX = 0.0;
    private double scaleY = 0.0;
    protected double maxX = 0.0;
    private double minX = 0.0;
    private double maxY = 0.0;
    private double minY = 0.0;
    private Point[] points = null;
    private Signal s = null;

    private void initPoints(int pointsToGenerate) {
        this.points = new Point[pointsToGenerate];
        double t = 0;
        double dt = this.maxX / pointsToGenerate;
        for (int i=0; i<pointsToGenerate; i++, t += dt)
            points[i] = new Point(t, this.s.v(t));
    }
    public AnotherSignalGraph(int pointsToGenerate, int width, int height) {
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.s = new Sinusoid(1000, 10, 0);
        this.maxX = (1 / this.s.frequency) * 2;
        this.maxY = this.s.amplitude;
        this.minY = -this.maxY;
        this.offset = super.getHeight() / 2.0;
        this.initPoints(pointsToGenerate);
        this.updateScale();
    }
    private void updateScale() {
        this.scaleX = super.getWidth() / (this.maxX - this.minX);
        this.scaleY = super.getHeight() / (this.maxY - this.minY);
        this.offset = super.getHeight() / 2.0;
    }
    private void drawSignal(Graphics2D g2D) {
        int x1, x2, y1, y2;
        g2D.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2D.setClip(0, (int)(this.offset - (this.s.amplitude * this.scaleY)), (int)(super.getWidth()), (int)((this.s.amplitude * 2 * this.scaleY) + 2));
        for (int i=0; i<this.points.length - 1; i++) {
            x1 = (int)(this.scaleX * this.points[i].getX());
            y1 = (int)(this.offset - (this.scaleY * this.points[i].getY()));
            x2 = (int)(scaleX * this.points[i + 1].getX());
            y2 = (int)(this.offset - (this.scaleY * this.points[i + 1].getY()));
            g2D.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }
    private void graphIt(Graphics2D g2D) {
        this.updateScale();
        this.drawSignal(g2D);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        this.graphIt(g2D);
    }
    private class Point {

        private double x;
        private double y;

        public Point(double x, double y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public double getX(){
            return this.x;
        }
        public double getY(){
            return this.y;
        }
    }
    private abstract class Signal {

        double frequency;   //Signal frequency in Hz
        double amplitude;   //Signal amplitude in Volt
        double initPhase;   //Signal initial phase in radians

        public Signal(double frequency, double amplitude, double degInitPhase) throws IllegalArgumentException{ //degInitPhase parameter specifies the initial angle phase in degrees
            this.frequency = frequency;
            this.amplitude = amplitude;
            this.initPhase = degInitPhase;
        }   
        public abstract double v(double t);
    }
    private class Sinusoid extends Signal {

        public Sinusoid(double frequency, double amplitude, double degInitPhase){   //degInitPhase parameter specifies the initial angle phase in degrees
            super(frequency, amplitude, degInitPhase);
        }
        @Override
        public double v(double t){  //t parameter indicates the specific time frame in seconds
            return super.amplitude * Math.sin((super.frequency * Math.PI * t) + super.initPhase);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new AnotherSignalGraph(50000, 600, 600));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is runnable now, but I can't reproduce the problem. It may be something specific to your system, such as an issue with the graphics driver.

Comment: It can't be that because i own a GTX 680 with the latest driver. I think i'm going to use the setResizable(false) method because i don't see any other oprion to avoid this problem. Thanks anyway.